# Multiple buffers using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, buffer, output

I'm doing a college assignment, and I'm trying to do multiple buffer and then clip them.

I'm using the For iterator. ArcGIS only gives me the last buffer as the output (I think, as when I add them to display, it only gives me the last one) and I need 4 separate shapefiles.

How do I make the ModelBuilder give me 4 outputs of the buffer and how do I insert them into the ModelBuilder?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it! I needed to put `%Value%` on the intersect to keep intersecting the outputs of the buffer/clip!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the model is not behaving as you are using feedback on your buffer tool. That is probably running as many times the For iterator runs then its the final buffer that then feeds into your Clip tool. Are you aware as of ArcMap 10.6 there is the [Multiple Ring Buffer tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/analysis-toolbox/multiple-ring-buffer.htm) which would avoid the need of feedback?